# Batch copy multiple folders and their subfolders into a merge folder

Tags: windows-7, batch, batch-file

I have a folder `X:\Export` that has several folders:

```
X:\Export
+---Export1
|   \---various files …
+---Export2
|   \---… and subfolders
+---Export3
|   \---etc.
\---etc.            (names vary widely)
```

Each “Export” folder has the same subdirectory structure, but they have different files (with possibly some name collisions). I would like to copy all the subfolders and the files of `X:\Export\Export1`, `X:\Export\Export2`, `X:\Export\Export3`, etc., to a folder `X:\Export\merged`, keeping the subdirectory structure.

Pseudocode of what I would like to do but cannot get working properly:

```
create new folder "merged"
for (every folder X in a given directory Y (i.e., X:\Export)
    copy every file in X keeping directory structure to "merged"
If conflict then overwrite
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
@echo off
md merged
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /ad') do (
    if not %%f==merged xcopy "%%f" merged /s /y
)
```

The `/y` option causes files to be overwritten without asking for confirmation.  Replace `/s` with `/e` if you want to copy empty subdirectories.

---

Additional explanation: `for /f "options"(optional) variable in ('command')` runs *command*, captures the output, assigns tokens (strings) from that output to the variable, and then runs the command(s) after the `do`.  `dir /b` means show only filenames (no attributes, no `.` and `..`); `dir /ad` means list only directories (no files).

The default behavior for `for /f` is to create a token from each line of output by taking all characters up to the first space.  The `"delims="` *option* tells it to take the entire line.  This bit of paranoia makes the script work even if you have directory names with spaces in them.  I probably could have gotten away with saying `xcopy %%f merged`; but I need the double quotes around `%%f` (`xcopy "%%f" merged`) to handle the case where `%%f` contains spaces.

Comment: It works if run through command prompt from that directory,
however if run by running the .bat file it defaults to c:\Windows.
how can i make it run in the directory where the .bat is located

forgot to mention that occasionally this is on a network drive.

Comment: @DjLenny: “… if run by running the .bat file it defaults to C:\Windows.”  I don’t understand how or why that would happen — what version of Windows are you running?  But to fix the problem, put a `cd` into the script; e.g., `cd/d X:\Export`.  If you need to be able to use it in different locations, make it take an argument (`cd/d %1`).

Comment: wondows 7, i figured out my problem, if i run it locally it works, if it is on an Unmapped network drive it doesnt work because of the UNC address of the file. Once i mapped the drive it worked just fine, also it worked in powershell. thanks for the script, works like a charm.

now a question for future understanding:

What is the relevance of "delims=" and ('dir /b /ad')
the rest i understand'

Comment: @DjLenny: I added more explanation to my answer.  (You can get even more information by typing `dir /?` and `for /?`.)  If my answer solves your problem, please “accept” it.